# How to display time series data as a bar chart in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to display a timeseries data as a bar chart but Grafana complains about

```
Bar charts requires a string field
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(footage_type) as _count_, BIN(time,24h) AS DAY FROM "footage"."footage" WHERE footage_type='VIDEO' group by BIN(time,24h) order by DAY
```

This is how my data looks in table form:

[image]

In timeseries form
[image]

But this happens in bar chart mode:
[image]

Likewise, the timestamps disappear in histogram mode:
[image]

What am I doing wrong  ?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer, it's quite simple, just change to bars.
[image]